# No module named 'psycopg2' -not in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

(I have tried the other options listed in similar threads, but either I didn't understand what to do, or they didn't work.)

I have installed Python 3 and PostgreSQL (that I'm using with pgAdmin4); I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit.
I have then installed Psycopg2 using the pip command.
If I go on Windows'Command Prompt and type `pip3 install psycopg2`, I get the message "requirement already satisfied" and the description of where it is saved.
However, when trying to connect it with Postgres (I have tried both on Pycharm and Jupiter on Anaconda) with the following code:

```
import psycopg2 as pg2

connect = pg2.connect (database = 'name', user = 'postgres', password = 'mypassword')
cursor = connect.cursor ()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM name;')
```

I get this error message: 
    import psycopg2 as pg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Can anybody help please?
as I have near to zero programming knowledge, I would appreciate easy to understand instructions.
Many thanks and bless you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Windows, there is a binary version of psycopg2 available online:
http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: Thanks for the link! This version is easier to download and install than the one I used before. It sill returns the same error when trying to connect, though. I was suggested to reinstall Python: hopefully this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, possibly because I saved my PyCharm on OneDrive rather than a normal folder on my laptop, the venv folder wasn't copied inside the project folder, so the system was unable to find whichever library I was installing (including Pandas). I unsinstalled PyCharm and reinstalled on a normal folder saved in my laptop and everything works fine. I hope this explanation is clear enough -if someone else has this problem, basically make sure you can see the venv folder inside your project folder on Pycharm.
Thanks @boy for your help